# How to setup realm object server with windows hosting and sync with server

Tags: android, realm

I just read about realm and its documentation. How to sync realm database to server SQL. Need clean explanation.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android's realm.io how to sync with server side MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903267/androids-realm-io-how-to-sync-with-server-side-mysql-db)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686619/keep-android-local-db-realm-in-sync-with-sql-server-with-minimal-network-overh

Answer (score 1):

1.) ROS can be hosted on Linux (CentOS, Ubuntu, ?) or Mac OS, or in the Cloud (Azure, DigitalOcean, Amazon EC2).

You cannot host ROS on Windows (yet?).

[See the documentation.](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/)

2.) It is possible to link existing SQL-based databases with Realm Object Server via a feature available **only in the Enterprise Edition**, which is called `Data Connectors`. It is available for Realm Node.JS.

You can read more about them [in the official documentation.](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/#data-connector).

---

There is an official Realm demo available for linking Realm with PostgreSQL [here (https://github.com/realm-demos/realm-dvdrental/)](https://github.com/realm-demos/realm-dvdrental/tree/a637cff660bf69fe942f1b24ca2d8346d3ddf150).